# Protect SPA with OAuth + OpenId, am I doing right?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, single-page-application

I am building a SPA, which use Keycloak as auth server, and will access some backend APIs.

I want to use the Resource Owner Password Flow, I think this flow avoid page jumping to keycloak, provide better UX.

after get Tokens(access token + refresh token) from keycloak, I store them in the browser's localStorage, and using refresh token to refresh access_token peroidicly.

I don't store tokens in sessionStorage, because if users close page, they need to login again.

Keycloak has a SSO session, when SSO session expires , refresh flow will fail, then I redirect user to login page.

Comment: From the security perspective: you are going to sacrifice security for better UX, because "Resource Owner Password Flow". PKCE flow is a standard flow for SPA and that jump to Keycloak has a security reason.

Comment: https://authguidance.com/ is a good source for this topic.